# Show list with limit and show more button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, material-ui

I'm trying to create a list of items where there are always 3 displayed per row and when i click on show more button another 3 will be displayed. Unfortunately I'm having trouble doing it using map and slice as using this approach always render 3 of the same items in one row and doesn't account for if the number of items is not dividable by 3. Any suggestions are welcomed

Here is what I have so far (the Math.random as a key is just a placeholder)

```
  const renderRow = (
    documentData: {
      fileName: string;
      description: string;
      contentUrl: string;
    }[],
  ) => {
    return documentData.slice(0, limit).map((documentsRow, i) => {
      return (
        <Grid key={Math.random()} container spacing={1}>
          <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
            {renderRowItem(documentsRow)}
            {renderRowItem(documentsRow)}
            {renderRowItem(documentsRow)}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    });
  };
```

Here is a working sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-typescript-list-with-load-more-button-fvbue

Comment: Do have any working example in stackblitz or codesandbox? it would make it easy to provide a solution.

Comment: "*... doesn't account for if the number of items is not dividable by 3*" - and what should the code do, what should happen, if the number of items are not divisible by three?

Comment: it should show only the modulo of three. If there are 14 items the last row should show 2. I will try to add a working example

Comment: @MrKhan Added working sample to bellow the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution which was as easy as updating the grid system of material-ui. Check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-typescript-list-with-load-more-button-fvbue for answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Grid,
  Paper,
  useMediaQuery,
  Container,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown";
import { useStyles } from "./useStyles";

import { DOCUMENTS_MOCK_DATA } from "./documentsMockData";

const LIMIT_MOBILE = 1;
const LIMIT_WEB = 3;

export const App: FC = () => {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("500");
  const inititalLimit = isMobile ? LIMIT_MOBILE : LIMIT_WEB;

  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(inititalLimit);

  const { button, buttonWrapper, root, paper } = useStyles();

  const showMoreDocuments = () => {
    setLimit(limit + 3);
  };

  const renderRowItem = (documentData: {
    fileName: string;
    description: string;
    contentUrl: string;
  }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
          <Paper className={paper}>{documentData.fileName}</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </>
    );
  };

  const renderRow = (
    documentData: {
      fileName: string;
      description: string;
      contentUrl: string;
    }[]
  ) => {
    return documentData.slice(0, limit).map((documentsRow, i) => {
      return (
        <Grid key={Math.random()} container spacing={1}>
          <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
            {renderRowItem(documentsRow)}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    });
  };

  const renderDocuments = (
    documentData: {
      fileName: string;
      description: string;
      contentUrl: string;
    }[]
  ) => {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        {renderRow(documentData)}
        <Grid className={buttonWrapper} container item xs={12}>
          <Button
            className={button}
            endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            onClick={showMoreDocuments}
          >
            show more documents
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Container className={root}>
      {renderDocuments(DOCUMENTS_MOCK_DATA)}
    </Container>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. The link doesn't work but from your example i can see that  there is only one row of items if i undestand i right. Please look at the code example I provided in the question edit

Comment: Dont you want on click for three rows to be added?Example: list 1 list 2 list 3. when clicked view more,  list 1 list 2 list 3 list 4 list 5 list 6

Comment: If the correct rendering of the items would be achived either showing 1 more row or 3 should be matter of changing parameter. Please refer to this code sample of the problem I provided - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-typescript-list-with-load-more-button-fvbue

Comment: Edited my answer. Check now.

Comment: Still doesn't work as intended. it is showing just one item in a row. I need to show 3 items in row and than 2 or 1 when the number of total item is not dividable by 3

Comment: where are you checking dividable by 3 in your code. There is no such thing here.

Comment: Yeah well that and showing the items correctly is the reason I have asked for help from stack overflow community